# How can I add a HTML element to a string and create the element to my component on the fly?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

So basically I'm trying to make my component as general as possible and I'm trying to create an `<a>` tag on the fly by extracting it from a string using the innerHtml property. My component properties are set in a conf.js file. The problem is that instead of this string `'Have you tyied our new dark theme?<a href="www.google.com">Text link</a>'` I get this string :

```
"Have you tyied our new dark theme?&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.com&quot;&gt;Text link&lt;/a&gt;".
```

How can I get the exact string so I can generate my `<a>` using the innerHtml property? I've tried using \ in front of < or " but with no success. I didn't find nothing that can help me on stack overflow so maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should include the code in your question that results in the escaped HTML string.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property?

Comment: @Salah no, the property is right. I just need to escape the characters. If i move the string inside my parent component from my conf.js file it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the mistake was because you didn't provide any code but I think this is what you need..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <span id="display"></span>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const link = 'Have you tried our new dark theme? ' + '<a href="www.google.com">Text link</a>';
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = link;
</script>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from the server side which was escaping the characters mentioned. The solution that I came up with is this

```
replaceCharacters(str:String):String {
str = str.replace(/&lt;/gi, '<');
str = str.replace(/&gt;/gi, '>');
str = str.replace(/&quot;/gi, '"'); 
return str;}
```

And in html I do this

```
[announcement]="replaceCharacters(liveBanner.announcement)"
```

Thanks for the time you allocated trying to help me guys.